# Python: AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'segments'

Tags: python, oop

I was trying to create a class called Snake. But when I run the code, it keeps saying "AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'segments'". Anyone can help, please?

```
from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITION = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]

MOVE_DISTANCE = 20

class Snake:

    def __int__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.create_snake()


    def create_snake(self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITION:
            snake = Turtle()
            snake.color('white')
            snake.shape('square')
            snake.penup()
            snake.goto(position)
            self.segments.append(snake)

    def move(self):
        for seg in range(len(self.segments), 0, -1):
            new_x = self.segments[seg - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.segments[seg - 1].ycor()
            self.segments[seg].goto(new_x, new_y)
        self.segments[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)
```

Comment: Pay attention to spelling. `__int__` is not the same as `__init__`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Pretty crazy that your code is _identical_ to someone else's, including the typo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73638431/attributeerror-snake-object-has-no-attribute-segments

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `__int__` to `__init__`
2. Add `-1` in 1st & 2nd parameter of `range()` :

```py
for seg in range(len(self.segments)-1, -1, -1):
```

Comment: Oh my god! You are right！Thank you so so much！